# how to change command line to point to Desktop

Tags: command-line, xgboost

i have to install Xgboost and i have done few steps and one last step is to wrap around the package xgboost . 
now i want to get cd desktop working but it showing an error as

```
    C:\Windows\system32>cd Desktop
    The system cannot find the path specified.
```

please help to resolve this issue thanks

Answer (score 0):

`cd` means 'Change Dir'. And I do not think that you have a 'Desktop' dir in `C:\Windows\system32`. To go to Desktop, use:

```
cd C:\Users\<username>\Desktop
```

and change `<username>` by your name.